# Docker - No executable found matching command "dotnet-/bin/MyApp.dll"

Tags: docker

I'm learning Docker. I have a Console app created with .NET Core. This console app has a Dockerfile in it. That Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

# Copy the compiled files
COPY . ./bin

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/bin/MyApp.dll"]
```

I intentionally want to copy the compiled files into the Docker images. I do NOT want to build the code on the Docker image due to issues with the dependencies. Still, when I select the play button in Visual Studio that says "Docker" I can see that the image gets successfully created via the "Output" window. In addition, my console app writes messages to the "Output" window as expected. For these reasons, I'm assuming my Dockerfile is correct.

Now, I try to run the build image from a command line outside of Visual Studio. From the directory where my .csproj file is located, I run `docker build .`. When I do this, I see the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   11.8MB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
 ---> 59184f8be664
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3a64d221c7f1
Step 2/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
 ---> 6691c7a1e6c7
Step 3/4 : COPY . ./app
 ---> e3e894ef7997
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/bin/MyApp.dll"]
 ---> Running in 355713fb3562
Removing intermediate container 355713fb3562
 ---> 88d4918847b9
Successfully built 78d4918847b8
```

I then run `docker container run 78d4918847b8` from the command line and I see the message:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-/bin/MyApp.dll"
```

I don't understand why I can run the image from Visual Studio but not from the command line myself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1126

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually means `File not found` (see https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1126 as suggested by @oneturkmen).

The reason the file is not found is because you are copying the files to  `./bin`  which is a relative path but the `ENTRYPOINT` is looking in `/bin` which is an absolute path, related to the root folder.

If you change your DOCKERFILE to:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

# Copy the compiled files
COPY . ./bin

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./bin/MyApp.dll"]
```

then it should work. Please note the  `./bin` in the `entrypoint`